# Username & password are added in the same column of the other saved user

Tags: c#

I have this code to save some csv data:

```
if (textBox2.Text ==textBox3.Text)
{
    string username = textBox1.Text;
    string password = textBox2.Text;
    string Fullname = username + "," + password;
               
                
    File.AppendAllText("Credentials.csv", Fullname);
                

    DialogResult r = MessageBox.Show("Account Created ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
    this.Hide();
    Form8 f = new Form8();
    f.Show();
}
```

After running this code a few times, I expect a file with 3 rows and 2 columns as below:

```
ori,babmdt
sami,123
yara,456
```

Whereas the file I created looks like this screenshot

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Comment: Side note: If you want to write CSV then I recommend you find a package on NuGet that can do that for you (like [CSV Writer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)). No need to reinvent how to write to CSV.

Comment: Also you should *never* store passwords in clear text. Instead store a cryptographically strong 1 way hash of the password, not the value itself and also not a 2 way encrypted value of that password.

Comment: im trying to take username and password from user in windows forms and putting it in csv

Comment: Looks like you want to write a new line...so, why not do that?

Comment: how can u pls write im new

Answer (score 2):

It's missing an end of line character at the end of each record. Change this:

```
string Fullname = username + "," + password;
```

to this:

```
string Fullname = $"{username},{password}\n";
```

But this is a profoundly unsafe way to handle passwords, and handling passwords is one of those things that's too important to do wrong, **even for practice/learning projects.** Go do some research on better patterns in this area before continuing.